# Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to perform a search from a form with 3 fields and with a like predicate, and y become this error: "Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0".

this would be my controller:

```
package cl.cbrtemuco.autoconsultas.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.jboss.logging.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import cl.cbrtemuco.autoconsultas.entity.Titulos;
import cl.cbrtemuco.autoconsultas.service.TitulosService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/autoconsultas")
public class TitulosController {

    @Autowired
    private TitulosService titulosService;

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    @GetMapping("/busqueda")
    public String buscarTitulos(Model theModel) {
        return "busqueda";
    }

    @GetMapping("/buscarTituloPorRsoc")
    public String buscarTituloPorRsoc(@RequestParam("razonSocial") String rSocial, 
                                      Model theModel) {
        List<Titulos> elTitulo = titulosService.searchTitulosByRazonSocial(rSocial);
        theModel.addAttribute("titulosPorRazonSocial", elTitulo);
        return "titulosPorRsoc";
    }

    @GetMapping("/tituloDetallesPorRSoc")
    public String tituloDetallesRSoc(@RequestParam("titulosId") int idTit, Model theModel) {
        //logger.info("showing form for update");
        Titulos elTitulo = titulosService.getTituloRSoc(idTit);
        theModel.addAttribute("titulo", elTitulo);
        return "detallesTituloPorRSoc";
    }

    @GetMapping("/buscarTituloPorNombre")
    public String buscarTituloPorNombre(@RequestParam("apellidoPaterno") String apPaterno,
                                        @RequestParam("apellidoMaterno") String apMaterno,
                                        @RequestParam("nombres") String nombres, Model theModel) {
        List<Titulos> elTitulo = titulosService.searchTitulosByNombre(apPaterno, apMaterno, nombres);
        theModel.addAttribute("titulosPorNombre", elTitulo);
        return "titulosPorNombre";
    }

    @GetMapping("/tituloDetallesPorNombre")
    public String tituloDetallesNombre(@RequestParam("titulosId") int idTit, Model theModel) {
        //logger.info("showing form for update");
        Titulos elTitulo = titulosService.getTituloNombre(idTit);
        theModel.addAttribute("titulo", elTitulo);
        return "detallesTituloPorNombre";
    }
}
```

THIS WOULD BE MY SERVICE:

```
    package cl.cbrtemuco.autoconsultas.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import cl.cbrtemuco.autoconsultas.dao.TitulosDAO;
import cl.cbrtemuco.autoconsultas.entity.Titulos;

@Service
public class TitulosServiceImpl implements TitulosService {

    @Autowired
    private TitulosDAO titulosDAO;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Titulos> searchTitulosByRazonSocial(String rSocial) {
        return titulosDAO.searchTitulosByRazonSocial(rSocial);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Titulos getTituloRSoc(int idTit) {
        return titulosDAO.getTituloRSoc(idTit);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Titulos> searchTitulosByNombre(String apPaterno, String apMaterno, String nombres) {
        return titulosDAO.searchTitulosByNombre(apPaterno, apMaterno, nombres);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Titulos getTituloNombre(int idTit) {
        return titulosDAO.getTituloNombre(idTit);
    }
}
```

AND FINALLY THIS IS MY DAO, here I think is the error:

```
package cl.cbrtemuco.autoconsultas.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import cl.cbrtemuco.autoconsultas.entity.Titulos;

@Repository
public class TitulosDAOImpl implements TitulosDAO {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Titulos> searchTitulosByRazonSocial(String rSocial) {
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query<Titulos> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("from Titulos where RazonSocial like :rSocial",
                Titulos.class);
        theQuery.setParameter("rSocial", "%" + rSocial.toLowerCase() + "%");
        List<Titulos> titulosEncontrados = theQuery.getResultList();
        return titulosEncontrados;
    }

    @Override
    public Titulos getTituloRSoc(int idTit) {
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Titulos datTituloRSoc = currentSession.get(Titulos.class, idTit);
        return datTituloRSoc;
    }

    @Override
    public Titulos getTituloNombre(int idTit) {
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Titulos datTituloNombre = currentSession.get(Titulos.class, idTit);
        return datTituloNombre;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Titulos> searchTitulosByNombre(String apPaterno, String apMaterno, String nombres) {
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query<Titulos> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery(
                "from Titulos where ApellidoPaterno like :apPaterno or ApellidoMaterno like :apMaterno or Nombres like :nombres", Titulos.class);
    theQuery.setParameter("apPaterno", "%"+apPaterno.toLowerCase()+"%")
                .setParameter("apMaterno", "%"+apMaterno.toLowerCase()+"%")
                .setParameter("nombres", "%"+nombres.toLowerCase()+"%");
        List<Titulos> titulosEncontradosNombre = theQuery.getResultList();
        return titulosEncontradosNombre;
    }

}
```

And Finally here is the stacktrace:

```
Hibernate: select titulos0_.idTitulos as idTitulo1_0_, titulos0_.AnoCancelacion as AnoCance2_0_, titulos0_.AnoTitulo as AnoTitul3_0_, titulos0_.ApellidoMaterno as Apellido4_0_, titulos0_.ApellidoPaterno as Apellido5_0_, titulos0_.CorrelativoTitulo as Correlat6_0_, titulos0_.FojasCancelacion as FojasCan7_0_, titulos0_.FojasTitulo as FojasTit8_0_, titulos0_.Nombres as Nombres9_0_, titulos0_.NumeroCancelacion as NumeroC10_0_, titulos0_.NumeroTitulo as NumeroT11_0_, titulos0_.RazonSocial as RazonSo12_0_, titulos0_.TipoRegistro as TipoReg13_0_, titulos0_.UbicacionPropiedad1 as Ubicaci14_0_, titulos0_.VueltaCancelacion as VueltaC15_0_, titulos0_.VueltaTitulo as VueltaT16_0_ from Titulos titulos0_ where ApellidoPaterno like ? or ApellidoMaterno like ? or Nombres like ?
feb 06, 2017 8:19:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [dispatcher] en el contexto con ruta [/AutoConsultas] lanzó la excepción [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0] con causa raíz
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.CharacterTypeDescriptor.wrap(CharacterTypeDescriptor.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.CharacterTypeDescriptor.wrap(CharacterTypeDescriptor.java:16)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:327)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2775)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1741)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1667)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1556)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:740)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:985)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:943)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2615)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2598)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2430)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2425)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1458)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1426)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1398)
    at org.hibernate.Query.getResultList(Query.java:417)
    at cl.cbrtemuco.autoconsultas.dao.TitulosDAOImpl.searchTitulosByNombre(TitulosDAOImpl.java:51)
    at cl.cbrtemuco.autoconsultas.service.TitulosServiceImpl.searchTitulosByNombre(TitulosServiceImpl.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.searchTitulosByNombre(Unknown Source)
    at cl.cbrtemuco.autoconsultas.controller.TitulosController.buscarTituloPorNombre(TitulosController.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And Finally my jsp file:

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lista</title>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <h2>Búsqueda de Títulos de dominio</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            <form action="buscarTituloPorNombre">
                <table>
                    <td>
                    <th>Búsqueda por Nombre:</th>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <tr>
                        <input type="textbox" name="apellidoPaterno" />
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <input type="textbox" name="apellidoMaterno" />
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <input type="textbox" name="nombres" />
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="add-button" />
                    </tr>
                    </td>
                </table>
            </form>
            <form action="buscarTituloPorRsoc">
                <table>
                    <td>
                    <th>Búsqueda por Razón Social:</th>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <tr>
                        <input type="textbox" name="razonSocial" />
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="add-button" />
                    </tr>
                    </td>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance, and please have the kindest regards.

Fernando

Comment: Perhaps provide the full stacktrace so we can pinpoint exactly where you might be experiencing this problem.

Comment: Please add the stack trace as code NOT as an image as that makes it totally unreadable and scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your three parameters are empty Strings. Can you paste your jsp as well?